# Tensorflow Image CNN AutoEncoder dimension issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I'm trying to make a CNN AutoEncoder using TensorFlow.

Here's my code:

```py
input_img = Input(shape=(288, 512, 3))

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)

x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

print(f'{decoded.shape} vs {x_train[0].shape}')
```

I expect the output shape to be (288, 512, 3) but I'm getting (None, 284, 508, 3).

I've tried adjusting some of the parameters but I'm not sure why I'm getting these dimensions or what I need to adjust to get the expected dimensions.

Comment: You forgot `padding=same` in the second-to-last convolution.

Comment: You should write that as an answer! It fixed the problem :)